# List comparison failure with Vampire Numbers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This code checks whether or not a combination of numbers produces a [vampire number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_number) but returns an incorrect True if x = 2947051 and y = 8469153.

```
def vampire_test(x, y):
    vamp = (list(str(x) + str(y)))
    prod = x*y
    vamp_check = list(str(prod))

    print vamp, vamp_check

    if '-' in vamp and '-' not in vamp_check:
        return False
    else:
        check = cmp(vamp.sort(),vamp_check.sort())
        if check == 0 and len(vamp) == len(vamp_check):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What's the issue and how can I improve the code I've already written?

Comment: your indentation is off. Please fix your post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a logic problem.  This line:

```
check = cmp(vamp.sort(),vamp_check.sort())
```

Will do `check = 0` every time, because the `.sort()` method of `list` sorts in place and returns `None`.

Comment: use `sorted(vamp)` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! Wouldn't have caught that otherwise.